# Code Implementation (Gunmen in Array)

Tags: arrays, row, implementation

There is a room with n rows and n columns, and there are gunmen in the room.
A gunman can see vertical or horizontal way, and cannot see over the wall or diagonal.
If a gunman see another gunman, they will shoot each other and only one man will survive.
We want all gunmen to be alive.
■: Wall
□: Empty space
♂: Gunman
For example, there is a room with 4 rows and 4 columns,

■■■□

□□□□

□■□□

■■■□

we can place 3 gunmen like below.

■■■□

□□□♂

♂■♂□

■■■□

However, we cannot place gunmen like below, because they are in the same line horizontally, one man will die.

■■■□

□♂□♂

□■□□

■■■□

We can place maximum 4 gunmen in this room, and there are 2 ways to achieve this.

■■■♂

□♂□□

♂■♂□

■■■□

2nd

■■■□

□♂□□

♂■♂□

■■■♂

could you help to write a program to calculate
1. The maximum number of gunmen we can place in the room below?
2. The number of ways to place gunmen in question 1?

thank you

Comment: What language / What have you tried / What didn't work? The question in this form is basic problem in the form of a SO post.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a refinement of the [8 queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle).

Comment: i'm so confused about implementation in a table. could u help me make a logic explanation using javascript? thankyou